# Can I use WM_COPYDATA to copy a non-struct?

Tags: winapi, wm-copydata

Lets say I have this class in foobar-shared.lib:

```
class FooBar {
    std::string m_helloWorld;
}
```

And I have a call in foobar-from.exe using SendCopyData like so:

```
extern HWND hMainWnd; // foobar-from.exe

{
FooBar fooBar;

HWND hWnd = FindAppWindow(); // foobar-to.exe
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = ('f'|('o'<<8)|('o'<<16));
cds.cbData = sizeof(FooBar);
cds.lpData = (LPVOID)fooBar;
SendCopyData(hWnd, (WPARAM)hMainWnd, (LPARAM)&cds);
}
```

When from a foobar-to.exe, I handle OnCopyData:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnCopyData(CWnd* pWnd, COPYDATASTRUCT* pCopyDataStruct) {
    if (pCopyDataStruct->dwData==('f'|('o'<<8)|('o'<<16))) {
        FooBar fooBar = *(FooBar *)pCopyDataStruct->lpData;
    }
}
```

This worked fine when FooBar was a struct, but now that it's a class I get this error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x0064ef81 in foobar-to.exe: 0xC0000005: 
Access violation reading location 0x0231dd7c.
```

I assumed originally that this was because my `fooBar` instance is on the stack, so I tried moving it to the heap but got a slightly different error (I can post the result here if necessary).

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649011(VS.85).aspx), "The data being passed must not contain pointers or other references to objects not accessible to the application receiving the data." so I suspect that this only possible with struct data. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are both correct and incorrect.

your problem here is that you don't know the implementation details of std::string. unfortunately, it seems this (standard) class uses a dynamicaly allocated buffer to store its character data. that's why `WM_COPYDATA` doesn't work with it.

but if your class does not contain a pointer to any external data, as suggested in the documentation, then it would be perfectly valid to copy it using `WM_COPYDATA`. unfortunately, this greatly limits the possible types for members of your class.

(think `WM_COPYDATA` is like sending data over a network: you should take care of serializing your class before sending it out in the wild...)